# Splitting configuration in Grails 3

Tags: grails, spring-boot, configuration

I'm currently in the process of migrating existing grails 2.5.x applications to grails 3.1.

What I really liked in the previous grails versions was the possibility to modularize my config files over multiple files with the `grails.config.locations` option, like:

```
Config.groovy
App.groovy
Logging.groovy
SpringSecurity.groovy
Quartz.groovy
...
```

As grails 3 is now based on spring boot, it uses a different configuration approach. But I couldn't figure a way to load my configuration from multiple files.

I've read about the `spring.config.location` option in spring, but it doesn't seem to do what I want. It seems to search for the application.groovy/application.yml in a different location, but that doesn't bring me back my splitted configuration files.

And I also do not like the fact that this option has to be set as an environment parameter. The application should just work without configuring extra environment variables or parameters.

That leads to my questions:

- Is it possible to bring back the configuration possibilities of the previous grails versions?
- Are there other methods in grails or spring boot to implement similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a Grails 3 plugin that mimics the way configuration files were handled in Grails 2:

http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/external-config

Answer (score 2):

`spring.config.location` will merge another configuration file with your Grails configuration, not overwrite it. We use it in an application that is deployed on several servers to override the defaults in our `application.yml` that's deployed with the app - we just include the keys that differ for that particular deployment.

One possible gotcha is that the database configuration cannot be overriden in this way. We work around that by placing database configuration settings into environment variables (e.g. `export DATABASE_URL=foo`, `export DATABASE_USERNAME=baz` and `export DATABASE_PASSWORD=bar`) and then using placeholders inside our configuration, like so:

```
environments:
    production:
        dataSource:
            url: ${DATABASE_URL}
            username: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
            password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

This database configuration part is a bit hacky, come to think of it the whole reason for '3 yaml files merged into one' is not argued very well, but that's the best we've managed to come up with.